# Need to validate Json data against Json Schema

Tags: json, powershell

Getting below error while validating the schema -

Could not read the JSON Schema : virtual://server/schema.json Error when resolving schema reference 'JsonValidate#/process.schema.json'. Path 'properties.configurationPayload.properties.processPayload', line 17, position 35.

JsonSchema -

```
{
    "$schema": "http://json-schema.org/schema#",
    "title": "Activity Payload",
    "description": "A json payload used to supply configuration to Data Factory activities.",
    "type": "object",
    "properties": {
        "processId": {"type": "integer"},
        "parentProcessId": {"type": "integer"},
        "displayName": {"type": "string"},
        "processType": {"type": "string"},
        "pipelineName": {"type": "string"},
        "isActive": {"type": "string"},
        "configurationPayload": {
            "type":"object",
            "properties": {
                "processPayload": {"$ref": "process/process.schema.json#"},
                "dataPayload":{"$ref": "data/data.schema.json#"}
            },
            "required": ["processPayload", "dataPayload"]
        }
    },
    "required": [
        "processId", 
        "parentProcessId",
        "displayName",
        "processType",
        "pipelineName",
        "isActive",
        "configurationPayload"
    ]
}
```

How can I resolve this, I am new to Json ? Currently I am validating it with online Json Scehma validator. I also want to know how can I validate Json data against schema using PowerShell script?

Answer (score 0):

Test an object against a provided schema

```
$schema = @'
{
  "definitions": {},
  "$schema": "http://json-schema.org/draft-07/schema#",
  "$id": "http://example.com/root.json",
  "type": "object",
  "title": "The Root Schema",
  "required": [
    "name",
    "age"
  ],
  "properties": {
    "name": {
      "$id": "#/properties/name",
      "type": "string",
      "title": "The Name Schema",
      "default": "",
      "examples": [
        "Ashley"
      ],
      "pattern": "^(.*)$"
    },
    "age": {
      "$id": "#/properties/age",
      "type": "integer",
      "title": "The Age Schema",
      "default": 0,
      "examples": [
        25
      ]
    }
  }
}
'@
"{'name': 'Ashley', 'age': '25'}" | Test-Json -Schema $schema

Test-Json : IntegerExpected: #/age

At line:1 char:37
+ "{'name': 'Ashley', 'age': '25'}" | Test-Json -Schema $schema
+                                     ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
+ CategoryInfo          : InvalidData: (:) [Test-Json], Exception
+ FullyQualifiedErrorId : InvalidJsonAgainstSchema,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.TestJsonCommand
False
```

- In this example, we get an error because the schema expects an
  integer for age but the JSON input we tested uses a string value
  instead.
- Refer to example 2 in this URL
  [Test-Json](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/test-json?view=powershell-7.1)